# How to get the src of img tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML as follow :

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li><a class="thumbnail" href="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_1-500x500.jpg" title="Canon EOS 5D"><img src="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_1-228x228.jpg" title="Canon EOS 5D" alt="Canon EOS 5D"></a></li>
    <li class="image-additional"><a class="thumbnail" href="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_2-500x500.jpg" title="Canon EOS 5D"> <img src="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_2-74x74.jpg" title="Canon EOS 5D" alt="Canon EOS 5D"></a></li>
    <li class="image-additional"><a class="thumbnail" href="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_3-500x500.jpg" title="Canon EOS 5D"> <img src="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_3-74x74.jpg" title="Canon EOS 5D" alt="Canon EOS 5D"></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to get the `src value` img. I have used the following code :

```
var imgTag =  $('.thumbnail').attr("href");
        console.log(imgTag);
```

It gives the `href` of the `a tag` but I want the src of the img tag just after the `a tag` what modification should I do ?

Comment: you want src value then get the `.attr('src')` instead of `.attr("href")`.

Answer (score 5):

image is child element of `.thumbnail`. You need to use:

```
$('.thumbnail').find('img').attr("src");
```

Change SRC of image:

```
 $('.thumbnail').find('img').attr("src", newSRC);
```

Comment: If I want to change the value of this src using jquery then how can I ?

Comment: @RohitashvSinghal `$('.thumbnail').find('img').attr("src", 'myNewURLHERE')`

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of the `src` attribute of your image, you need to request the `src` attribute, not the `href` attribute.

To get the child of an element, use the [child (direct descendant) selector](https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) `parent > child`.

In your case:

```
$('.thumbnail > img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get source using

```
$('.thumbnail img').attr('src');
```